# App crash only if im not using debugger. Unable to overcome the situation. What should I do?

Tags: react-native, redux, expo

I'm facing a pretty ugly issue that I'm not able to overcome by myself, I just don't get it.

A short summary of my app purpose: You can find food around and make orders to restaurant owners.

I wrote a helper function that allows me to decide if the restaurant is open or closed based on its schedule “horarioSemanal” property.

This function take the restaurants queried from firestore as arguments and depending in some conditions it decide which value of the property “disponible” (available) it deserves.

The thing is that it works pretty well! So well that I published the changes through expo, and as expo has updates over-the-air and I have my app in both apptore and Google play it reached all my users…

None of my users were able to use my app until I removed the changes because I was unable to detect the issue. In my simulator it worked 100% but when the app was deployed crashed almost instantly.

Testing, testing, and testing I finally come to the issue but I still can't figure out what the hell should I do to overcome this situation.

The app while I use the js debugger it works perfectly! but when I turned off this new module I wrote doesn't work.

I recorded a video so you can see the same I'm watching on my screen:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9-t8-3XzKc

this is the action where im dispatching the action:

```
import { restaurantesHorarioValidado, validaDisponibilidadComidas } from '../../src/3-ResultadosComponents/Librerias/DisponibilidadHorario';

export const searchResultsInLocation = (ubicacion) => {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const docRef = db.collection('Restaurantes').where('abierto', '==', true).where(`zonaOperativa.zonaConsulta.${ubicacion}`, '==', true).get();
  const restaurantesIDS = [];
  return (dispatch) => {
    const holder = [];
    dispatch({
      type: BUSQUEDA_DE_RESULTADOS,
    });
    docRef.then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        holder.push(doc.data());
        restaurantesIDS.push(doc.data().id);
      });
      dispatch({
        type: DESCARGA_RESTAURANTES_ABIERTOS,
        restaurantes: restaurantesHorarioValidado(holder)
      });
    })
    .then(() => {
      const comidasRefs = [];
      restaurantesIDS.forEach(restaurant => {
        const ref = db.collection('Comidas').where('restaurantID', '==', `${restaurant}`).get();
        comidasRefs.push(ref);
      });
      return Promise.all(comidasRefs).then(results => {
        const comidas = [];
        results.forEach(resto => {
          resto.forEach(comida => comidas.push(comida.data()));
        });
        dispatch({
          type: DESCARGA_COMIDAS,
          comidas: validaDisponibilidadComidas(comidas, restaurantesHorarioValidado(holder))
        });
      })
      .then(() => dispatch({
            type: BUSQUEDA_DE_RESULTADOS,
          }))
      .catch(err => console.log('error; ', err));
    });
  };
};
```

here is how the reducer is handling the action:

```
case DESCARGA_COMIDAS:
  return { ...state, comidas: action.comidas };
case DESCARGA_RESTAURANTES_ABIERTOS:
  return { ...state, restaurantes: action.restaurantes };
```

this is the module I wrote and I'm using to create the object that the action creator send:

```
const diasDeSemana = ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado'];
const today = new Date().getDay();

const hoyAbre = (horario) => {
  if (horario) {
    const JornadaHoy = horario.find(jornada => jornada.dia == diasDeSemana[today]);
    return JornadaHoy;
  }
  return false;
};

export const isRestaurantAvalaible = (horario) => {
  const Today = new Date();

  if (hoyAbre(horario)) {
    //Si el restaurant abre hoy
      //Evalua si está abierto
    const horarioApertura = () => {
      const nuevoDia = new Date(`${Today.getFullYear()}, ${Today.getMonth() + 1} ${Today.getDate()} ${hoyAbre(horario).horario.apertura}:00`);
      return nuevoDia;
    };

    const horarioCierre = () => {
      //Si horario de cierre es hoy
      const nuevoDia = new Date(`${Today.getFullYear()}, ${Today.getMonth() + 1} ${Today.getDate()} ${hoyAbre(horario).horario.cierre}:00`);
      //Si el horario de cierre de hoy es pasado las 00:00
      const cierraTomorrow = new Date(`${Today.getFullYear()}, ${Today.getMonth() + 1} ${Today.getDate() + 1} ${hoyAbre(horario).horario.cierre}:00`);

      if (nuevoDia.getHours() <= 8) {
        return cierraTomorrow;
      }
      return nuevoDia;
    };

    const isNowOpen = Today.getTime() >= horarioApertura().getTime();

    const isNowClosed = Today.getTime() >= horarioCierre().getTime();

    //Si está abierto
    if (isNowOpen && !isNowClosed) {
      return { estado: 'abierto' };
    }

    //Si abre mas rato
    if (hoyAbre(horario) && (Today.getTime() < horarioApertura())) {
      return { estado: 'abre pronto', horarioApertura: horarioApertura() };
    }

    //Si ya cerró
    if (isNowOpen && isNowClosed) {
      return { estado: 'ya cerro', horarioCierre: horarioCierre() };
    }
  }

  //Si hoy no abre
  if (!hoyAbre(horario)) {
    return { estado: 'No abre hoy' };
  }
};

export const restaurantesHorarioValidado = (restaurantes) => {
  const restaurantesModificados = restaurantes.map(restaurant => {
    return { ...restaurant, disponible: isRestaurantAvalaible(restaurant.horarioSemanal) };
  });
  const restaurantesAbiertos = restaurantesModificados.filter(restaurant => restaurant.disponible.estado == 'abierto');
  const restaurantesProximosAbrir = restaurantesModificados.filter(restaurant => restaurant.disponible.estado == 'abre pronto');
  const restaurantesCerrados = restaurantesModificados.filter(restaurant => restaurant.disponible.estado == ('ya cerro' || 'No abre hoy'));

  return [...restaurantesAbiertos, ...restaurantesProximosAbrir, ...restaurantesCerrados];
};

export const validaDisponibilidadComidas = (comidas, restaurantes) => {
  //Se le agrega la propiedad "disponible" del restaurant dueño
  const comidasModificadas = comidas.map(comida => {
    const Owner = restaurantes.find(restaurant => restaurant.id == comida.restaurantID);
    return { ...comida, disponible: Owner.disponible };
  });

  const comidasDisponibles = comidasModificadas.filter(comida => comida.disponible.estado == 'abierto');
  const comidasProximosAbrir = comidasModificadas.filter(comida => comida.disponible.estado == 'abre pronto');
  const comidasNoDisponibles = comidasModificadas.filter(comida => comida.disponible.estado == ('ya cerro' || 'No abre hoy'));

  return [...comidasDisponibles, ...comidasProximosAbrir, ...comidasNoDisponibles];
};
```

this is the error I get once I turned off the js debugger:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'restaurant.disponible.estado')]

Stack trace:
  src/3-ResultadosComponents/Librerias/DisponibilidadHorario.js:65:98 in <unknown>
  src/3-ResultadosComponents/Librerias/DisponibilidadHorario.js:65:62 in restaurantesHorarioValidado
  store/actions/2-ResultadosActions.js:55:50 in <unknown>
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
  node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
  ...
```

As it suggest there is some error with promises I tried making those functions work as promises. The errors disappear but the I didn't get the object back...

The question is this How the hell may this work just when the debugger it's on and not when it's turned off?

what should I do to get my life back?

Comment: The problem is likely an async action that completes in time when you have the debugger on but fails to do so when running at speed (the object isn't there yet when you try to access it). This is actually a fairly common problem.

Comment: That's the same I thought. I tried the examples above as promises but with no success. Now I will chain all as promises and try again. Thanks for your answer @JaredSmith!